# unable to identify unique element during webscraping using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [this site][1] using Selenium and Python. Below is the updated code with help from the community:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
url="http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=170831&Exchange=0#navFinancialsAnnual"
browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
financials = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='myNavbar']//a[contains(text(),'Financials')]")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(financials)
actions.perform()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Annual Results')]").click()
all_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='PrevDetails']")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250);")
all_data.click()
```

The element is still not visible, as evident from the error Stack:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Annual Results')]").clic
k()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response    
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Comment: Why *Selenium should click the xpath element*? You don't use any clicks in your code... Can you share more details about what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @SolitaryReaper The `xpath` you mentioned `.//*[@id=PrevDetails]` is invalid. Which element are you trying to click exactly? Thanks

Comment: i wish to scrape the table that will pop up on clicking that element (refer pic). have updated the code for click function.

Comment: can you change `browser.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id=PrevDetails]')` to `browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='PrevDetails']").click()` or `browser.find_element_by_id('PrevDetails').click()` and let me know

Comment: Instead of `the table` and `that element` and `refer pic` Can you consider updating your manual steps? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB yes, thats the problem. the link (all data) in the webpage exists, and the xpath for that is .//*[@id=PrevDetails] - which selenium doesnt pick up.!

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution sorry, both of them dont work. im still getting the same error - no such element.

Comment: @DebanjanB: I intend to scrape the annual result table that pops up after i visit the site.
(1) Visit the site http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=170831&Exchange=0#navFinancialsAnnual
(2) Click Financials-->Annual Results
(3) Click All data
(4) Copy the data from the pop up table.

Comment: @Solitary Reaper, this is different error, is your element in iframe ?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution the element is created as one of the item in cards (guess, it should be a sharepoint website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

The following code block will open the URL `http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=170831&Exchange=0#navDashboard`, Mouse hover over `Financials`, click on `Annual Results` and finally click on `All Data` which brings up the `Axtel Industries All Annual Results` popup:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('http://www.marketsmojo.com/Stocks?StockId=170831&Exchange=0#navFinancialsAnnual')
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
financials = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='myNavbar']//a[contains(text(),'Financials')]")
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(financials)
actions.perform()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Annual Results')]").click()
all_data = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='PrevDetails']")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 250);")
all_data.click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: thanks for ur efforts, but unfortunately it doesnt solve the problem. im getting the same error --> element not visible

Comment: What do you mean by same error `element not visible`? On which element?
 On which line? Update your current code and error stack trace in the Question area please. Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated Answer and let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a very lot mate. I had to make few changes to the code (to close an alert box) and then copy the data. But, anyways that was all based on ur code. Thanks again.!

Answer (score 0):

Change the locator from xpath for all_data to a css "#navFinancialsAnnual #PrevDetails" and try.